# Rails Association belongs_to marking as optional dynamically in class and mixin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have came across a scenario in an existing code base.

Im upgrading Rails to 5.1 from 5.0 and we now need to define relationships as `optional` where its not required.

I have came across a situation where we have a `class` and a `mixin` that are causing conflict.

Is there a way to define the relationship with the :user so that it will meet requirements in both scenarios.

In the Model, a user is not required, but within the mixin, a users presence is validated, causing the conflict.

As the Mixin is `included`, writing a proc to evaluate whether to mark the relationship as optional by using a function/proc results in the class method being used at runtime. If you prepend the mixin instead, it will default to the method in the mixin, meaning either way they conflict.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

```
module Mixins
  module Foo
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
   
    validates :user, presence: true, if: :user_is_required?

    private

    def user_is_required?
      <!-- LOGIC HERE -->
    end 
  end
end
```

At an engine level.. the mixin is included as so:

```
::Foo.include(Mixins::Foo)
```

Comment: Honestly, it is not clear what _exactly_ is the problem. You can make a validation conditional, you can go with a fully customized validations (either as a custom instance method or a separate validator class) etc...

Comment: Its tricky to explain, apologies for the confusion. When you trying to write specs, for moth the model, and tfor the mixin... you want to assert that the model, has the user as optional. But because the mixin is being loaded into the model, you have both a presence validation on he user(coming from the mixin) and a belongs_to marked as optional on the model. The two things contradict each other.